# In JavaScript, is the significance of doing (0, function_name)() versus function_name()?

Tags: javascript, syntax, babeljs

I was playing around on the [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl), when I noticed, for:

```
import {foo} from 'bar';
foo();
```

Babel generates:

```
'use strict';

var _bar = require('bar');
(0, _bar.foo)();
```

whereas for:

```
function foo() {}
foo();
```

Babel generates the expected:

```
"use strict";

function foo() {}
foo();
```

My question is with regards to the last line of the first Babel output, is there a reason for doing `(0, _bar.foo)();` instead of `_bar.foo()`? Does it handle some sort of corner case if `_bar.foo` is `undefined`?

I found these resources. From MDN comma operator [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

and from MDN grouping operator [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping):

> The grouping operator ( ) controls the precedence of evaluation in expressions.

From my understanding, from those two statements, `(0, _bar.foo)` should evaluate to `_bar.foo`?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. The difference to a plain `_bar.foo()` is the value of `this` inside `foo`.

Comment: Yes, the linked question helps a lot, thanks! I don't know why it didn't come up when I googled this.